# What was the price of Bitcoin in USD when bitcoin cash forked?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

What was the USD price of Bitcoin on the various exchanges when bitcoin cash forked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some BTC-USD prices from the larger exchanges about 10 min after the fork.

**Coinbase**
[01.08.2017 12:30:00 UTC

$2818](https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/candles?start=2017-08-01T12:30:00.00000Z&end=2017-08-01T12:31:00.00000Z&granularity=60)

**Bitstamp**
[01.08.2017 12:30 UTC

$2725](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFVJL.jpg)

**Bitfinex**
[01.08.2017 12:30 UTC

$2717](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Omb.jpg)

**Cex.io**
[01.08.2017 12:30 UTC

$2795](https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20170801/BTC/USD)

**OkCoin**
[01.08.2017 12:30 UTC

$2721](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml5Jc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The price of Bitcoin was around $2900 USD on August 1st. The price slightly went down to around $2600 the same day.